# Multi user role in laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I want to redirect to the user's dashboard according to role. I have created a separate table for the user role and a separate table for the user. I don't understand how I can do that.

This is my middleware code

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Auth::check()){
            return redirect()->route('login.user')->with('error', 'Please login first');
        }

        if(Auth::user()->role == 1){
            return $next($request);
        }

        if(Auth::user()->role == 2){
            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }
    }
```

This is my user role table

| id | user_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | admin |
| 2 | user |

This is my user table

| id | user_name | user_role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | admin | 1 |
| 2 | user | 2 |

I would be very happy if you could help me.

Comment: have you defined role in user Model ?

Comment: yes, I can't figure out how to build a relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Irrelevant to your post since you already got a perfect answer by @Mátyás Grőger (Don't forget to mark it as answer if it's satisfactory), but I would advise you don't mention the type of the table in your columns. Meaning if you're in the users_table, it's best not to prefix your columns with "user". On a different note, the "user_type" column in the roles_table can be better named "role". Trying to follow simple and common naming conventions will mean that people reading your code will have an easier time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the User Model you have to define the role relationship.

Put this to your User Model:

```
    public function role()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'user_role_id');
    }
```

Of course you have to have the Role model, but I guess you already have that

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Auth::check()){
            return redirect()->route('login.user')->with('error', 'Please login first');
        }

        if(Auth::user()->role->user_type == 'admin'){
            return $next($request);
        }

        if(Auth::user()->role->user_type == 'user'){
            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }
    }
```

Another solution could be without relationship just like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Auth::check()){
            return redirect()->route('login.user')->with('error', 'Please login first');
        }

        if(Auth::user()->user_role_id == 1){
            return $next($request);
        }

        if(Auth::user()->user_role_id == 2){
            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }
    }
```